# Is there a way to use Select-String to print the line number and the matched value (not the line)?

Tags: powershell

I am using powershell to search several files for a specific match to a regular expression.  Because it is a regular expression, I wan't to only see what I have programmed my regex to accept, and the line number at which it is matched.

I then want to take the matched value and the line number and create an object to output to an excel file.

I can get each item in individual select string statements, but then they won't be matched up with each other

```
Select-String -Path $pathToFile -Pattern '(?<={\n\s*Box\s=\s")14\d{3}(?=",)' | 
    Select LineNumber, Matches.Value 
#Will only print out the lineNumber

Select-String -Path $pathToFile -Pattern '(?<={\n\s*Box\s=\s")14\d{3}(?=",)' | 
    Foreach {$_.matches} | Select value 
#Will only print matched value and can't print linenumber
```

Can anyone help me get both the line number and the matched value?

Edit: Just to clarify what I am doing

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $directory -Include *.vb,*.cs -Recurse
$colMatchedFiles = @()
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $fileContent = Select-String -Path $file -Pattern '(?<={\n\s*Box\s=\s")14\d{3}(?=",)' |
        Select-Object LineNumber, @{Name="Match"; Expression={$_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value}}
    write-host $fileContent #just for checking if there is anything
}
```

This still does not get anything, it just outputs a bunch of blank lines

Edit: What I am expecting to happen is for this script to search the content of all the files in the directory and find the lines that match the regular expression. Below is what I would expect for output for each file in the loop

```
LineNumber Match
---------- -----
324        15
582        118
603        139
...        ...
```

File match sample:

```
            {
            Box = "5015",
            Description = "test box 1"
            }....
            {
            Box = "5118",
            Description = "test box 2"
            }...
            {
            Box = "5139",
            Description = "test box 3"
            }...
```

Comment: Ok. Now: What bit of text do you want to extract? The number after `Box = "`?

Comment: The expected output above the file match sample is what I want.  I want the last 3 digits of the box number.  I wouldn't mind all the digits of the box number.  I can figure out the regex though, it is just getting the matches line number and value matched

Comment: OK finally we get what you are after. See Example 2 in my answer.

Comment: See Example 3 in updated answer - outputs only matches where line before each match contains `{` character. Lesson learned: Explain exactly what you want the regex to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Example 1

Select the `LineNumber` and group value for each match. Example:

```
$sampleData = @'
prefix 1 A B suffix 1
prefix 2 A B suffix 2
'@ -split "`n"

$sampleData | Select-String '(A B)' |
    Select-Object LineNumber,
    @{Name="Match"; Expression={$_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value}}
```

### Example 2

Search *.vb and *.cs for files containing the string `Box = "<n>"`, where `<n>` is some number, and output the filename, line number of the file, and the number on the `box =` lines. Sample code:

```
Get-ChildItem $pathToFiles -Include *.cs,*.vb -Recurse |
  Select-String 'box = "(\d+)"' |
    Select-Object Path,
    LineNumber,
    @{Name="Match"; Expression={$_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value -as [Int]}}
```

This returns output like the following:

```
Path             LineNumber Match
----             ---------- -----
C:\Temp\test1.cs          2  5715
C:\Temp\test1.cs          6  5718
C:\Temp\test1.cs         10  5739
C:\Temp\test1.vb          2  5015
C:\Temp\test1.vb          6  5118
C:\Temp\test1.vb         10  5139
```

### Example 3

Now that we know that we want the line before the match to contain `{`, we can use the `-Context` parameter with `Select-String`. Example:

```
Get-ChildItem $pathToFiles -Include *.cs,*.vb -Recurse |
  Select-String 'box = "(\d+)"' -Context 1 | ForEach-Object {
    # Line prior to match must contain '{' character
    if ( $_.Context.DisplayPreContext[0] -like "*{*" ) {
      [PSCustomObject] @{
        Path = $_.Path
        LineNumber = $_.LineNumber
        Match = $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the structure of Matches?  I am confused with why you access arrays when looking at Matches
    $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value

Comment: The `Matches` array is a collection of `MatchInfo` objects. To get the first matching substring, we get value of the the first match from the second group. (The first group is the entire matching string.)

Comment: See my edit above.  For some reason, what you have works, but will not work with what I am doing... I don't really understand why

Comment: Please update your question to give an example file name you want to match, which substring you want to capture, and what the output should look like.

Comment: Updated.  The output that I am expecting is exactly the same as your example, I am just iterating through multiple files and outputting the results

Comment: You need to provide also some sample file names.

Comment: I want to read the content in files, not the file names themselves, but I have added sample file names.  Pretty much any file that ends with *.cs or *.vb

Comment: Sorry, I meant: You need to provide some sample file content of what you want to match.

Comment: So your example works... I just want to make sure that the previous line that is matched has a curly brace. I can't quite get my regex right

Comment: It is helpful be specific in the original question. When you are not specific or change it after the fact, this is known as "scope creep."

Comment: I was specific in the original question. I included my regex string which clearly is looking on multiple lines.  I found the problem though.  Apparently Select-string goes line by line unless you use get-content -raw and pipe it to the select-string.  This causes another problem where it can't actually tell the line. I really appreciate your help on this, but I might have to go about doing this differently unless you have any thoughts

Comment: I disagree that you were specific enough (that's why I kept having to ask follow-up questions). You needed to tell what you want the regex to _do_.

Comment: You are a genius.  Thank you for your help.  I will try to be more specific next time I ask a question

Comment: Great; the question was interesting once I understood what you were wanting to do.